# Django Rest Framework view doesn't work when called from DRF API tool

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the following DRF ViewSet:

```
class ServiceStatusForListViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    pagination_class = None
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = models.ServiceStatus.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.ServiceStatusForListSerializer
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, SearchFilter, OrderingFilter,)
    search_fields = ('service__item__product__name', 'service__client_name')
    filter_fields = ('id', 'service', 'service__item', 'service__item__product')
```

This view works perfectly when a GET request is sent by a React frontend application, and it returns the expected response:

[image]

The problem is when I send a GET request from the browser (Chrome):

[image]

It just never returns, and the "loading" indicator keeps spinning forever. All other endpoints work well from DRF API tool, but this one.

**EDIT**

The endpoint works fine when GET request is sent from Postman. It only fails when the request is sent from the browser.

Comment: what's `CustomModelViewSet`?

Comment: @HåkenLid, sorry, I fixed it. It was something I was trying. The viewset fails the same with a `ModelViewSet`

Comment: Django shouldn't make any difference between http requests made using javascript or from the address bar. Check the "Network" tab in chrome devtools. You can inspect each request and response in more detail there.

Comment: I had a smilar issue but it was because my response was large that the browser had trouble rendering it with the DRF html, css, js files. Not sure if that is your issue here.

Comment: @Daniel Nope, it is not that, the response is only six records long, and it is paginated.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably working on postman because you're including a login token in the authorization field among the request headers. try removing the line:  `permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)` and retry making that request with the browser.